# Making a conditional with multiple addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, conditional-statements, addeventlistener

I'm currently trying to make a function call after an onClick for a link which is specified by the variables, but only one of the links work, I've been using firebug and it isn't reporting any errors, so I don't know what the problem may be. The code is as follows:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var jpbutton = document.getElementById("jpbutton");  
    var usbutton = document.getElementById("usbutton");
    if (usbutton.addEventListener) 
    {
        usbutton.addEventListener("click", run, false);
    }
    else if(jpbutton.addEventListener)
    {
        jpbutton.addEventListener("click", execute, false);
    }  
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: well with your if statement there it will only ever add the usbutton listener, its always going to return true for the first if. replace `else if` with just `if`

Comment: What do `run` and `execute` do?

Comment: run and execute are function calls

Comment: Patrick you are absolutely correct! I definitely have over looked that, i'm still new to javascript. I appreciate your help